# Running functional tests written in C#(MS test) as a perf test

Tags: c#, performance-testing, mstest, functional-testing

We have functional tests written in C#. The tests do the following

1. API Call to set up data
2. Call the API of interest (GET OR POST)
3. Assert and delete set up data

I know the right way of doing a perf test is to use url based testing using tools such as JMeter. However, the team does not want to spend time 'redoing' that. We want to run the functional tests to run as perf test ( running thousands of times simultaneous to mimic actual user). However, I couldn't find a tool that will do run this tests a number of times simultaneously and give me some sort of visual or summary data about time it takes to run each test and how many times a test fails etc.  Does anyone know about a tool that can do this

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests are not going to reliably load test an application.  You can run unit tests in parallel with most test frameworks including MSTest. But they won't scale adequately for a real load test and it's going to be a real mess trying to get any decent results from it. (they run multiple tests in parallel not single tests multiple times in parallel)

If you're trying to re-use the unit/load tests that you already have then your best bet is probably to create a small custom test runner that'll handle calling the current code in parallel.

But from having gone down that path many times before I would caution that the risk is that you end up dumping more time into the custom test runner than it'll take to learn one of the many load testing tools available.